# Powershell stops writing to Transcript when file is not available

Tags: powershell, scripting

The below code uses [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to resize images if *Test* is included in the name.

```
if (-Not(Test-Path "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\$currentDate.txt"))
   {
   New-Item -Path C:\Users\Test\Desktop -Name "$currentDate.txt" -ItemType "file"
   Write-Host "Created new file "$currentDate.txt""
   }

   $ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
   Stop-Transcript | out-null
   $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
   Start-Transcript -path "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\$currentDate.txt" -append

   Get-ChildItem $currentDir -recurse -filter "*_Test.*" |
   %{ Write-Host ($count++) ($_.FullName)|
      magick $_.FullName -resize 220x120> $_.FullName
   }
   Stop-Transcript
```

I want is to create a file with the current date if not exist, and then write-host to it, the problem is when the file is not available it will be created but no thing is added to it. However if the file is available it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Start-Transcript` has a known [bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3014136/powershell-transcript-file-doesn-t-contain-the-correct-information-in-windows-server-2012-r2) that causes this behaviour, [discussed](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cecc4f32-28c8-4bdc-be63-49ce3d396625/powershell-4-starttranscript-does-not-log-writehost?forum=winserverpowershell) on TechNet.